# MariaDB row lock for read

Tags: php, mariadb

I have two scripts using PHP7 / 10.4.14-MariaDB . Both update the same value in the database.
Script1 uses a transaction; script2 does not. Script1 is executed slightly earlier than script2.

The pseudo-code for both are:

Script 1:

```
$objDb->startTransaction();
$objDb->query("select ID,name from table1 where name='nameB' limit 1 FOR UPDATE ");
if($objDb->totalRows()>0)
{
    $objDb->get();
    $objDb->query("update table1 set name ='nameBB' where ID=".$objDb->row['ID']."  ");
}
sleep(3);
$objDb->commit();
```

Script 2:

```
$objDb->query("select ID,name from table1 where name='nameB' limit 1");
if($objDb->totalRows()>0)
{
    $objDb->get();
    $objDb->query("update table1 set name ='nameCC' where ID=".$objDb->row['ID']."  ");
}
```

If I would execute script2 with a transaction then the final database-value is 'nameBB' since script2 waits until script 1 is committed, as expected.

However in the current script2 example (without a transaction) the final database-value is 'nameCC'. I expected it also to be 'nameBB'. Apparently no read-lock is placed for the ID of table1.

How can I make sure that regular select queries ( without transaction / autocommit ) are put in read lock?

help appreciated

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: There's no such thing as not having transactions. Individual statements exist within their own transaction. So, your second query has two transactions, one after the other. As locks are released when a transaction closes, the ONLY way to get a lock to persist between two statements is with a transaction. Transactions and locks go hand in hand. So, why are you trying to avoid transactions?

Comment: I made an edit to clarify the question and tags, because you say you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are two different products. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have been changing since then, and you should no longer consider them as compatible. Answers for one may not necessarily be correct for the other, so you should tag your questions for the database product you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

The Script 1 starts an transaction and updates name to 'nameBB'. This happens inside the transaction. This means that the change is not visible to other processes until it is committed.

The Script 2 is free to read the "old" data, but it is blocked to update the row until the transaction from Script 1 is either committed or it is rolled back.

When the Script 1 commits, the lock is released and the Script2 performs the update resulting 'nameCC' as name column value.

Note that the two scripts are independent of each other. It could have been that the Script 2's read happened before the row was locked by Script 1. The result would have been the same, so locking the read is not the answer.

What you should do, is avoid using separate SELECT/UPDATE and when possible do:

```
update table1 set name ='nameCC' where name='nameB' limit 1
```

If you hve two processes updating the same data simultaneously, you need to decide which of the updates is the valid one.

If you want to use separate SELECT/UPDATE, you can for example use updated_at datetime column to make sure your update matches the read.